# Does excel stop looking after it finds one record when using a formula like 'countif'?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

If I include a condition like `=if(countif(X:X,A1)>0,"found","not found")` in an Excel formula, will Excel stop the `countif` after it finds one matching record, or will it keep looking to find the total count in the whole column, return that count, and check if that value is `>0`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to search a value of A1 within a range X:X ? Then `COUNTIF(X:X, A1) > 0` is enough

Comment: Yes. The short of it. `=COUNTIF(X1:X10, ">0")` Will count all cells in X1:X10 that are greater than Zero. Hence, this will yield TRUE. Then you have this `=IF(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: Lookup functions like VLOOKUP or MATCH stop as soon as they find a match.  Count functions, like COUNTIF, go through all of the data in the specified range and count every qualifying one.  They pretty much have to or every count function would never count higher than 1, which wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: @fixer1234 that makes sense, I just wasn't sure if there might be some optimisation whereby knowing that they are testing a "greater than" condition, it aborts the count early.  It's conceivable that they might code the calculation to inspect the whole formula for instances where continuing to execute the function inside is superfluous.

Comment: Excel does that with logic like IF tests.  It doesn't bother exhaustively analyzing branches that it has determined can't affect the result.

Comment: So I suppose a more efficient approach than `COUNTIF(X:X,A1)` would be `NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,X:X,0))` or `ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,X:X,0))` (assuming A1 is not a condition such as "<2" or "beginstr*")

Comment: MATCH could involve fewer comparisons if there actually is a match, particularly if the match isn't near the end of the list.  However, the comparison algorithm might not be the same, in which case each comparison might not take the same time for the two functions.  But I would expect a match near the start of a long list to be a lot faster than a countif of the whole list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works from the inside out. `COUNTIF` returns a value, and then you are testing that value in the `IF`. The `IF` test is not part of the design of `COUNTIF`, and `COUNTIF` is not aware of what you are using the value for.